# ArrayStoreException while converting List<String> to Text Array MapReduce

Tags: java, mapreduce

In a mapreduce code, while converting list to array of (org.apache.hadoop.io.Text) Text type, receiving ArrayStoreException.

```
List<String> testList= new ArrayList<String>();
            testList.add("testData1");
            testList.add("testData2");

            Text[] testArray=testList.toArray(new Text[testList.size()]);
```

but when i dont add any value to the list and then convert it to array, it works fine(with null values). Can some one please point my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't store `String`s in a `Text` array (`Text[]`).

You can store them in a `String` array (`String[]`) :

```
String[] testArray=testList.toArray(new String[testList.size()]);
```

> when i dont add any value to the list and then convert it to array, it works fine

It only works since you are creating an empty array in this case, so nothing is stored in it.

If you must produce a `Text[]` that contains the data from the source `List<String>`, you have to iterate over the List and produce the Text instances yourself:

```
Text[] testArray = new Text[testList.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < testList.size(); i++) {
    testArray[i] = new Text(testList.get(i)); // assuming the Text class 
                                              // has such a constructor 
}
```

Comment: thank you for pointing this out. Can you suggest a work around for this

Comment: @user72 I already suggested how to fix this. From a `List<String>` you can get a `String[]`. If you require a `Text[]`. you'll have to iterate over the Strings of the List and construct the Text instances yourself.